# Force.com Site & Public Calendar

Tags: force.com-sites, permissions

I am trying to expose Salesforce Public Calendar on to Force.com Site. I performed the below:

[1] Updated the Public Calendar Sharing Settings to include "Salesforce Calendar Site Guest User".
[2] Enabled the VF Page for the Site.

**Observation:**

[1] The VF page (exposing the Public Calendar) when accessed via a Tab with in the Application works fine.

[2] In "Public Access Settings" I do not find any object pertaining to Calendar. I could not assign access permissions for the Profile.

[3] When Previewed as Admin it throws the below Error:

*Authorization Required
Page not allowed for profile:/sfcalendar/00U/c*

[4] Enabled the Debug Logs for the Site User and found the below:

28.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
13:14:41.027 (27034000)|EXECUTION_STARTED
13:14:41.027 (27087000)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|066G0000001xnF1|VF: /apex/Unauthorized
13:14:41.104 (106363000)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
13:14:41.104|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

13:14:41.106 (106403000)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|VF: /apex/Unauthorized
13:14:41.106 (106413000)|EXECUTION_FINISHED

**Questions:**
Is Public Calendar Accessible via Force.com Sites? What settings should I check further?

Comment: Is this a SF Portal operating through sites? If so, what kind of User license do you have? Calendars reference the Event/Activity Object which aren't accessible to HVCP license and a number of other licenses which could be an issue for a public calendar. I suggest you check your license and then check the docs.

Comment: @crmprogdev, thanks 4 the valuable inputs, there are no portals (customer/partner) involved. Its just a single Force.com Page containing the below code.
<apex:page controller="CalendarController" action="/00U/c?cType=1&cal_lkid={!calendarId}&md0={!YEAR(TODAY())}&md1={!MONTH(TODAY())-1}">
Please wait...
</apex:page>
calendarId returns the row id of the Public Calendar. Another option tried was with the IFRAME which did not work either.

Comment: @crmprogdev, Each site when created has a unique guest user and each guest user has a unique profile that can be accessed via the site public access settings. 
The below are those: 
User License: Guest User License
Profile: Salesforce Calendar Profile

The underlying fact is that via the "Public Settings" I am not able to give *permissions* to access Public Calendar Object (none of the Objects Action/Event are available to be selected in the *Profile - Salesforce Calendar Profile*)

Comment: @crmprogdev, does setting up Customer Portal to promote the Guest user into Portal user help? it requires authentication; but I believe it helps Non-SFDC Licensed users to self register once and view the Public Calendar. Your thoughts!

Comment: I strongly suspect that regardless of what you try, you'll need to "mirror" the calendar objects out as custom objects via triggers. Once that's done, you may not need to have a portal at all (just Sites) since it would be a read-only object. Being honest, creating Portal Users can be a Royal PITA. If visitors can view what you want as a Guest user or a Sites User, then that should suffice and would be the preferred way to go if the Public Calendar isn't considered sensitive information.

Comment: @crmprogdev, this helps ... even as a portal user one would not have access to Calendar. An idea is already logged. Your suggestion to have the details from the Event standard Object mirrored into the custom Object might help; just wondering how would I build the Calendar View over the custom Object?

Comment: Once you have the data available, I'd be thinking in terms of looking around for any kind of standard calendar app that's already available on the web. I'd suggest a Google search or looking to see what jQuery plug-ins might be available since most of them are free. No need to reinvent the wheel. ;) Good luck!